# Чи вживане слово основування як термін?

Tags: вибір-слова, терміни

Один із прихильників пуристичних тенденцій в українській термінології (. Кульчицький І. Проблемні аспекти локалізації окремих термінів з інформатики / І. Кульчицький, Б. Філь //Вісник Нац. ун-ту «Львівська політехника». Серія «Проблеми української термінології» — 2012. — № 733. — С. 196—200.) пропонує такі замінники іншомовних термінів:

> options – вибір можливостей, password – гасло,  bullets – значники, 
>   endnote – прикінцева примітка,  footnote – присторінкова примітка,  та 
>   прикладної лінгвістики (парсинг – розбір, стемінг – основування).

зазначаючи при цьому, що перевагу треба віддавати термінам українського походження перед запозиченими. 
Викликає сумнів слово *основування*. В Тлумачному словнику в 11т. його немає. Чи дійсно такий варіант є кращим?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko на жаль, "прихильники пуристичних тенденцій" нерідко суть не стільки за чистоту мови, а за "аби не як у росіян". В результаті отримуємо ще одне значення для вищенаведеного полонізму "гасло" замість запозиченого через російську галліцизму "пароль".
Через їхню таку діяльність у багатьох загалом нейтральних учасників мовних баталій складається дещо упереджене ставлення, яке дехто міг би порівняти з відразою, хтось інший - зі зневагою, хтось - із недовірою.

Answer (score 1):

І справді, такого слова немає в жодному із відомих словників української мови. Та й на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/steminh) відповідником до слова "стемінг" пропонують не "основування", а "обруб", "дезафіксація" тощо. Однак, якогось єдиного популярного варіанту там ще немає.

Варто зазначити, що хорошим варіантом буде "дезафіксація", але ще краще замінити частинку "дез-" на "зне-", а "-афіксація" на "-чепіння" (див. [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/afiks)). І отримаємо варіант "знечепіння".

Хоча, здається, слово "основування", утворене від "[основуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/osnovuvatysja)" не буде перечити правилам [українського словотвору](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/morfologija_i_pravopis/slovotvir_imennikiv/6-1-0-87):

> Від дієслів абстрактні назви творяться переважно за допо­могою
>   суфіксів -анн(я), -енн(я), -інн(я) (навчання, споглядан­ня, мислення,
>   вдосконалення, терпіння, розуміння), рідше —б(а) (лічба, журба), -к(а)
>   (суперечка, здогадка).

Comment: А чому *-чепіння*?

Comment: А Вам варіант "знечепінь" здається кращим?

Comment: А, я зрозумів! Це від *чіплятись*, якось одразу було не зрозуміло.

Comment: Думаю, що Словотвір - це цікавий проєкт, але йому не вистачає системи контролю щодо правильності описів та системи контролю щодо компетентності термінів. Як це впровадити - не знаю, але дуже потрібно.

Answer (score 1):

#### Значення слова stem

> a [stem](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stem) - a central part of something from which other parts can
>   develop or grow, or which forms a support.
>
> - the part of a word that is left after you take off the ending
>
> [Стовбур](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80) - Основна наземна частина дерева або куща, від якої
>   ростуть гілки.
>
> [Основа](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) - Нижня опорна частина чого-небудь (будівлі, споруди,
>   конструкції і т. ін.).
>
> [Корінь](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C) - Головна частина слова (без афіксів), що виражає його
>   основне (лексичне) значення й не поділяється на морфеми.
>
> [ОСНОВА](http://8next.com/umova/2060-umova_149.html) – частина слова без закінчення. Основу зверху позначають
>   квадратною дужкою. Основа слова може складатися з таких частин:
>   префікса (підказка), кореня (казка, казочка, казати) і суфікса (казка,
>   казочка, казк ар).
>
> Частина слова без закінчення називається [основою](http://files.pidruchnyk.com.ua/uploads/book/Ukrainska_mova_3klas_Zaharijchuk.pdf).

#### Значення дієслова to stem

> to [stem](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stem) - to stop something unwanted from spreading or increasing
>
> ЗОСЕРЕ́ДИТИ - Див. зосере́джувати.
>
> ЗОСЕРЕ́ДЖУВАТИ - Збирати, об'єднувати, розташовувати, скупчувати в
>   одному місці, в одних руках, в однієї людини і т. ін.

#### stemming

> [stemming](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stemming) - present participle of stem
>
> [Stemming](https://searchenterpriseai.techtarget.com/definition/stemming) is the process of reducing a word to its word stem that
>   affixes to suffixes and prefixes or to the roots of words known as a
>   lemma

Коли мова йде про основу слова, то в українській мові це називається "[Будова слова](http://files.pidruchnyk.com.ua/uploads/book/Ukrainska_mova_3klas_Zaharijchuk.pdf)" і не відокремлюють окремо дію відокремлення основи слова. Виділення основи слова є частиною будови слова.

Але саме слово stemming може мати й інші значення, а не тільки стосовно будови слова. І по суті означає "виділення основи з чогось".
[Приклади](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/stemming) використання в інших випадках.

Не знайшов перепон для використання слова основування у значенні "виділення основи з чогось".